# ¿Alguna solución para este problema que tengo con mi código en python?

Tags: python, python-turtle

Esto es para un proyecto de programación, necesito dibujar 2 figuras solicitando al usuario el numero de lados, y el tamaño de los lados de la primera figura. Esto lo logré, y el programa funciona adecuadamente. El error está en que la segunda figura debe estar inscrita en la primera, y con todas las figuras me sirve, excepto con el círculo. Y a pesar de que he investigado y he leído libros no logro llegar a una solución. Les agradecería que me ayudaran. El código que llevo hasta el momento es el siguiente:

```
from turtle import *

shape('turtle')

bgcolor('green')

lados= int(input("Introduzca el número de lados de la figura que desa dibujar, o indique si desea dijubar un círculo escribiendo el 0: "))


tam1= int(input("Introduzca la medida de lado de la figura en centímetros: "))


lados2= int(input("Introduzca el número de lados de la figura que desa dibujar, o indique si desea dijubar un círculo escribiendo el 0: "))

tam1= tam1*40

if lados==0:

    circle(tam1)
else:

    if lados == 3 or 6:

        for i in range (0, lados):

            forward(tam1)

            right(360/lados)

if lados2==0:

    circle(tam1)

else:

    if lados2 == 3 or 6:

        for i in range (0, lados2):

            forward(tam1)

            right(360/lados2)

speed(1)
input("Presiona Enter para salir...")
```

Comment: Ambos círculos te están quedando del mismo radio, no? Cómo te están apareciendo en pantalla?

Comment: De acuerdo a la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.circle), con `circle(x)` dibujas un círculo de radio x, cuyo centro está `x` unidades a la izquierda de la posición actual de la tortuga...

Comment: Es que realmente no son dos círculos, sino, por ejemplo un círculo y un cuadrado. Pero uno debe de quedar dentro del otro. Y no, queda uno al lado del otro. Y respondiendo a la pregunta del radio, todo tiene el mismo tamaño ya que se deriva en función de una misma variable

Comment: La clave con la tortuga es saber en qué posición queda después de cada instrucción. con `position` y `heading` siempre sabrás dónde quedó después de pintar y cómo devolverla a la posición en la que estaba antes de pintar la primera figura...